# AWS: samconfig.toml: mask default configuration

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sam

In AWS samconfig.toml, is it possible to only mask values instead of specifying the full set of config parameters for each individual configuration?values?

Here's an example:

```
[default]
[default.deploy]
[default.deploy.parameters]
stack_name = "my-stack"
region = "us-east-1"
...

[differentRegion.deploy.parameters]
region = "us-east-2"
```

When called with `sam deploy --config-env differentRegion`, the stack name should be `my-stack` and `region` should be `us-east-2`